I cannot open form designer in my Visual Basic program
How can I open the form designer in Visual Basic?
I'm making a Windows form program using Visual Basic 2022, but I cannot find the form designer. When I press the compile button, the form I've designed appears, but I cannot edit it because I cannot access the design menu.
Am I missing something? Sorry for somewhat dumb and silly question, but my programming skill's literally worse than a 'noobie' in this world.
I've right-clicked almost every item in the [View] menu and left-clicked almost every tab in the properties window, but I cannot find a menu option like "Open form designer." I've also re-installed the whole Visual Studio.

Have you tried double-clicking your form in the Solution Explorer?

When I press the compile button: what button would that be? -> the form I've designed appears: so you have used the Designer. Are you trying to design the Form while running the app?

I double-clicked designer.vb and .vb content but it only showed coding page... that CUI interface.

Compile button - the green triangle button in the toolbar. Am I wrong?
Yes, I've used the designer form, where I can design using GUI interface, but it suddenly disappeared, only in a certain project.

The green button runs the application. You cannot design a Form / Window while the app is running. Stop it with the red button. Or close the starting Form / Window

In the code page, try F7 or shift F7
